# Checkbox value is not getting updated in Jquery impromptu

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes with some test boxes in jquery impromptu. While saving the updated value, I can see the updatd data for textbox, but not for checkbox.

Here is the code. Please check and guide me on this.

Code to update checkbox value:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')!=undefined){
        f.completion=true;
    }else{
        f.completion=false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use `this.checked`, it will give you whether checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Whenever the I am unchecking my checkbox, the value is not getting passed to my spring controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        f.completion=true;
    }else{
        f.completion=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should quote to the undefined:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')!="undefined"){
        f.completion=true;
    }else{
        f.completion=false;
    }
});
```

Or better to use like this:

```
if($(this).attr('checked')!=true){
```

Or just like this:

```
if($(this).attr('checked')){
```

Or even better to use like this:

```
    if(this.checked!=true){
```

You may also use prop() method instead of attr() method.

Comment: Why not `this.checked`?

Comment: yeah that too but tagged only in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.prop('checked')` in your `if` statement instead of `.attr('checked')` and check for `true` or `false`, also see the below snippet that I always use for dynamically generated checkboxes.

```
// check all and unchecked all functions for a group of checkboxes 
$(".group1Checkbox").click(function () {
"use strict";
$('.group1Checkbox').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
$('.group1Checkbox').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```